# Simultaneous use of Palantiri

Tags: communication, palantiri

Palantiri [need to be oriented](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Palant%C3%ADri#Usage) correctly to See:

> To communicate with another stone, the viewer would orient himself and look toward the location of that stone, and the two stones would automatically connect with one another unless one was being used in another conversation.

What would happen if one person were to physically connect to two (or more) Palantiri simultaneously?

Could they:

1. See farther/two things at once?
2. Act as a bridge between the destination Palantiri?

Comment: Like a network?  Perhaps they might call it the Automatic Relay Palantiri Advancements Network?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a race condition to see which one connects first?

Comment: @DavidW: That's disgusting...but I still upvoted it!

Comment: Are you implying the user is considered part of the connection as an exclusive resource?

Comment: The user's heads would all simultaneously explode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The palantir of Osgiliath used by Denethor *could* be used to eavesdrop on the "conversations" of others, specifically between Sauron and Saruman, so it's possible to have more than a two-way communication and extend the "range" of the palantiri that way.  But if you mean what would happen if, say, Saruman had a palantir in each hand, if he'd be able to double the range? I don't think so. It might even kill the user because using a palantir requires an immense strength of will, so using two would likely require double the strength; Denethor only used a single stone and he aged unnaturally from it over time. Were he to have used two, even if he had the willpower, the effects would likely have killed him.